# Android AutoSync data from Backend on a daily basis

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am working on this Cordova Android application where there is a need to update the local database by syncing data from backend automatically every 24 hrs. Any ideas on how to implement this.

We initially thought of going with seTimeout in javascript but then it would not work if the app is not running always.

Also we do not want to use push notifications So any ideas how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)
You can schedule notifications for a time interval and do stuff in the callback method when the notifications gets executed.